# How can I control which file errors are reported in?

Tags: errors, package-writing

Here is a class that can generate errors in two ways. It yields an error unless given one of two options, and also it has a command that always yields an error.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{foo}[2014/05/06 foo]

\newif\iffoo@foo
\newif\iffoo@bar
\DeclareOption{foo}{\foo@footrue}
\DeclareOption{bar}{\foo@bartrue}
\ProcessOptions

\iffoo@foo
    \AtBeginDocument{foo}
\else
  \iffoo@bar
    \AtBeginDocument{bar}
  \else
    \PackageError{foo}{Always use foo or bar option}{Please}
  \fi
\fi

\newcommand*{\foobar}{
  \PackageError{foo}{The \protect\foobar\space command is obsolete}{}}
\endinput
```

The document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{foo}

\begin{document}

hello
\foobar

\end{document}
```

triggers them both:

```
! Package foo Error: Always use foo or bar option.

See the foo package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.16 ...foo}{Always use foo or bar option}{Please}
```

and

```
! Package foo Error: The \foobar command is obsolete.

See the foo package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.7 \foobar
```

I would like the first one to be more like the second one. That is, I'd like it to indicate the `\usepackage{foo}` line instead of a line in the sty file. After all, that's what the user of the class should edit.

How can I control that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't control it, the last line of the TeX error message is issued by the underlying TeX engine showing where it was when an error is detected. It is not under the control of the macro layer

The only thing you can do is change where the error is detected, For example if you use

```
\AtBeginDocument{\PackageError{foo}{Always use foo or bar option}{Please}}
```

Then you get

```
! Package foo Error: Always use foo or bar option.

See the foo package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.4 \begin{document}
```

Comment: Ah! And with `\AtEndOfPackage` instead I get at least close to the goal, but unfortunately the line after.

Comment: @pst latex has got to the next line looking for an optional argument before running the code  the user would have to put and \relax after \usepackage to tell latex not do that, but that's not really a feasible option to expect that)

Comment: I don't get the `\relax` part right. Can you please show that in your answer?

Comment: (I meant to ping @DavidCarlisle in my last comment.)

Comment: @pst it's not usable here really, I was thinking about the comment about `\relax` at the bottom of page 19 of `texdoc clsguide` but here if you wanted the error to be on the usepacakge line rather than the line after, the _user_ would have to do `\usepackage{yourpackage}\relax` but if the user knew to do that they know enough not to make the error....

Comment: OK, then I guess I'm out of luck. I think it would be really great with some lower-level support for indicating where an error is, since getting to the exact file and line of an error is so very useful. For cases like this maybe some hook in `\usepackage` that the package can add stuff to.

Comment: @pst No, as I said in my initial comment this is not configurable from within TeX you would need to change TeX-the-Program somehow.

Comment: I didn't mean anything beyond the "change where the error is detected", only that that could be even more flexible with more hooks. With for example `\let\origusepackage\usepackage` and `\renewcommand\usepackage[2][]{\global\def\afterusepackage{}\origusepackage[#1]{#2}\afterusepackage}` a package could do `\global\def\afterusepackage{\PackageError{foo}{xxx}{yyy}}` and the error will be reported immediately after the usepackage call. (There are probably multiple issues with that, so I certainly don't suggest that should be used as is.)

Comment: @pst the problem is \usepackage has an optional date argument at the end, and tex has already moved to the line looking for that argument _before_ the package is input, which is why the reported line is the one after. If you redefine \usepackage as in your comment you remove that argument so the error in the endpackage hook is reported on the usepackage line, but any document using the date argument breaks